# VBAProject(PERSONAL.XLSB) not showing in Excel 2013 upon startup

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

When I open Excel 2013 on my desktop, my personal.xlsb is there and the code runs beautifully. But when I  open the very same workbook on my server, it is not  there, and the code won't run correctly from my QAT. This is not an issue on other computers in my office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Personal.xlsb may be disabled. Try the following:

1. Click the Office button
2. Click Options
3. Click Add-ins
4. Select Disabled Items in the Manage dropdown list
5. Click on Go
6. Select your Personal.xlsb
7. Enable the file